# find the x and y co-ordinates of the center and middle point inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, html5-canvas

I am using svg and d3 and I need to draw a circle right at the center and middle of a div.  How do I calculate the coordinates of the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get center of div like this:

```
var $this = $(this); // targeted div
var offset = $this.offset();
var width = $this.width();
var height = $this.height();

var centerX = offset.left + width / 2;
var centerY = offset.top + height / 2;
```

Where centerX and centerY are the coordinates of center.